# Can't find the Editor in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, editor

Its been a year ago I've used wordpress. I remember the Editor in the appearance. But now i can't find it. Is it because Im using the free version, it won't be possible to use the Editor?
Thanks

Answer to question:
There's a big different between wordpress.com and wordpress.org!

Comment: Main Menu->Appearance->Editor

Comment: No, its not there

Comment: It may be disabled by adding `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
` somewhere in config or theme files.

Comment: I have to ask here,are you asking for theme editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are at Self-hosted Version**

At wordpress.com there never has been an editor button because we've never been able to edit theme files (we all share the same files on this multi-user platform). Here we have the CSS editor at `appearance > custom design` which requires the Custom Design Upgrade and allows you to only make changes to the CSS. It does not let you edit theme files.

There is an editor to edit theme files on the self-hosted version of wordpress.

**If you are not at Self-hosted version you can try:**

– deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works & you can see the Appearance -> Editor option, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).

– switching to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.

– resetting the plugins folder by FTP or PhpMyAdmin. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.

– re-uploading all files & folders – except the wp-content folder and wp-config.php & root .htaccess files – from a fresh download of WordPress. Make sure that you delete the old copies of files & folder before uploading the new ones.

**Take Look What is benifits of WordPress.org**

- You can customize a theme
- You can install plugin
- Maintain hosting thing yourself.
- Core functionality override is possible.
- No registration with WordPress.org is required.

Comment: Ok. When I go into plugins, I can't deactivate. Is it because its the free version?

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you.

Comment: you are working on url  example.wordpress.com or example.com?

Comment: example.wordpress.com

Comment: oh..So you don't have  plugin menu there.

Comment: Nope, and not the editor. So I guess i have to pay for these functions

Comment: Thats the different! It was .org I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: So,You have to mark this as completed.If you agree with me. :)

Comment: ok,I hope things will clear now.You can refer codex for wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to your file manager (ask your web host) or use FTP to locate the wp-config.php file on your server:

1. Download and open wp-config.php on your computer. Any text editor (notepad) should be able to do this.
2. Scroll down the file to find - `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`
3. Change true to false: `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);`
4. Save the file and upload it back again. (remember to save as .php if using notepad as editor.

The theme editor should now be available in the Appearance tab.